# Is it possible to rotate the text above the bar graph in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

There is the possibility of rotating the texts that are in the upper part of the graphical bars I am using Charts3.2.2 of CocoaPods.
Attached image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are using label for that then you can do this

In 90 degree:

```
youLabelName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:CGFloat.pi/2)
```

In 180 degree:

```
youLabelName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:CGFloat.pi)
```

you can add - sign infront of cgfloat (-cgfloat.pi/2) or (-cgfloat.pi)

this may be the solution for your problem.

Comment: I do not use labels, I use CHARTS properties or there is another way to do it.
I sent you the code that I use   -----> let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Ingresos")       
chartDataSet.valueFormatter = formtValor()  ------------->  
 final class formtValor: IValueFormatter{
   func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {

       let intVal = String(format: "%.2f", value)

       return "$\(intVal)"
   }
}